# Mapping and cardinality question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying  A First Course In Topology
by R. Conover

I am looking at Chapter 2.

In the following:

**1.4 Definition** For two sets A and B,|A|$\leq$ |B| if there is
a 1-1 function from A into B, and |A|<|B| if there  is a 1-1 function from A into B but there is *not* a 1-1 function from
*A onto B*( no surjective function)

Q1)How do I exhibit a mapping between A an B when one set
is larger.ex let A $\subset B \subset C$ and |A|=|C| then
|A|=|B|=|C|

Q2) How do l show |A| <|B| ? . Can l have an example.
Help

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Perhaps you could phrase it more clearly?

Comment: Which one don’t you understand

Comment: Did you miscopy the definition? You say "1-1 function from $A$ to $B$" twice. I think the second one is supposed to be "from $B$ to $A$."

Comment: I don't understand your Q1. As to your Q2, Schroeder-Bernstein tells you that a bijection exists between two sets if you can find injections from each to the other; it *explains* why this definition of $\lt$ does what you want it to do, but is not really relevant. The way you exhibit a map is the way one exhibits anything: "define the map $f\colon A\to B$ as follows...."

Comment: Nope l did not miscopy @ Arturo Magidin  So in any such proof that uses Schroeder-Bernstein ,l can give any map ?

Comment: @Plotinus: The definition you give is nonsense: it literally says that there has to both be and **not** be a 1-1 function from $A$ to $B$. If that is what the book says, then it's a typo. The second "$A$ to $B$" needs to be "$B$ to $A$", or else the definition is self-contradictory. Again, this is a definition; you don't need Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein for anything. If you want to invoke C-S-B, you only need to provide injections going both ways.

Comment: Your question is very open. It doesn't have a general answer, it depends on the specific case. The property |A|<=|B| says such a mapping exists, but gives no clue as how to build it. As an example the space of continuous functions has the same cardinal as the real numbers, but finding an explicit bijection is very very difficult.

Comment: Here is the exact text with explanation. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Ah, my mistake; the second is "onto", not "into". Maybe I need a new prescription... Please do not remove the text, though; images are not accessible, and cannot be searched.

Comment: One misconception you *must* get over is that a set containing another in anyway implies the set containing the other is in any sense "bigger" than the other.  If $A \subset B \subset C$ but $|A| =|B| = |C|$ for example $A=$ all odd positive integers; $B=$ all positive integers; $C= $ all integers.  But $C$ is *NOT* bigger than $B$ and $B$ is *NOT* bigger than $A$.

Comment: Although the definition of says an into mapping exists, it isn't to be implied *finding* that mapping, nor proving that an onto mapping doesn't exist is supposed to be *easy*.

Comment: Are you asking if $A \subset B \subset C$ and $|A|=|C|$ how to prove $|B|=|C|=|A|$?  The identity map is an one-to-one map so that proves $|A|\le|B|\le|C|$.  As $|C|=|A|$ we know a bijection $f:C\to A$ must exist.  Let $f':C\to B$ by $f'(x)= f(x)$.  That is one to one so $|C| \le |B|$.  So we have $|C| \le |B|$ and $|B|\le |C|$ by by SchroederBernstein we have  $|B|=|C|$. A bijection $g:B\to C$ exist and bijection $f:C\to A$ exists.  So $f\circ g$ is a bijection from $B$ to $A$ and $|B|=|A|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $A\subset B\subset C$ and $|A|=|C|$, then there is a 1-1 function from $A$ into $B$ (the inclusion) and a 1-1 function from $B$ into $C$ (the inclusion). In addition, $|A|=|C|$ means there is a 1-1 function form $A$ **onto** $C$, and hence one from $C$ **onto** $A$. Let $f\colon C\to A$ be such a function. Then the composition $i\colon B\hookrightarrow C\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}A$ is a 1-1 function from $B$ into $A$. At that point, you can just *invoke* Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein and conclude that because you have a 1-1 function from $A$ to $B$ and one from $B$ to $A$, then there is a 1-1 function from $A$ **onto** $B$. You don't need to exhibit an explicit one: that's the whole point of having a theorem telling you there is one. Also, since you don't actually know what $f$ is (you just know it exists) you would not be able to give an explicit bijection between $A$ and $B$ anyway.
2. There are many easy finite examples: we can show that $|\{1,2\}|\lt |\{1,2,3\}|$ by showing that there is a 1-1 function from $\{1,2\}$ into $\{1,2,3\}$ (the map $1\mapsto 1$, $2\mapsto 2$) and then noting that there can be no 1-1 function from $\{1,2\}$ **onto** $\{1,2,3\}$, because that would require at least one element mapping to $1$, another to $2$, and third one to $3$; but $\{1,2\}$ has just two elements, so this is impossible. Cantor's Theorem gives a proof that there can be no 1-1 function from a set $X$ onto its power set $P(X)$. And of course, Cantor's diagonal argument shows that there can be no 1-1 function from $\mathbb{N}$ onto the real numbers in $(0,1)$. In general, to show $|A|\lt|B|$ you exhibit a 1-1 function from $A$ to $B$, and then you argue that there can be no function $A\to B$ that is *onto*. Exactly how one does that will depend on the precise nature of $A$ and of $B$. There is no recipe to follow that will always bake that cake, no matter what $A$ and $B$ are.